# why would rebuild index reduce btree leaf numbers

Tags: index

> **Rebuilding an index might reduce the number of leaf nodes by about 20%**
>   - 30%. The most you can possibly expect from this reduction is 20%-30% for very expensive operations like a FULL INDEX SCAN. The typical
>   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN gain of an index rebuild is 0%-2% because the depth
>   of the index is not reduced by the rebuild.

In my understanding , the btree structure/shape is almost uniqe. why would rebuild the btree reduce leaf numbers ?

is there any uncertainty around the btree build process ?

[Myth: Indexes Can Degenerate](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/myth-directory/indexes-can-degenerate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A living index often accumulates empty spaces in the leaf nodes — e.g. due to deletes. Rebuilding the index will make sure all leafs are filled up to the configured threshold.

Note that I wrote **it *might* reduce the number of leaf nodes**. If have only inserts on this table, you won't even get this benefit.

Also keep in mind that the overall context of this article is an argument *against* rebuilding indexes without really good reason.